# How to avoid WAL logs

Tags: arangodb

I often insert millions of records into a new (often volatile) collection, thereby using an AQL statement, e.g. like this:

```
FOR w IN relatedAffils
    COLLECT from = w._from, to = w._to INTO agg
    INSERT { "_from": from, "_to": to, "weight": LENGTH(agg), 
       "fromAff": DOCUMENT(from).affiliation,
       [...SNIP...]
       } INTO relatedAffilsAggregated
```

I understand, that the bigger the objects are, the longer it takes to execute that. But the execution time seems not to increase in a linear way, but much heavier. In consequence, changing the volume a bit already can lead to 10-50 times more execution time. One possible reason might be that the WAL log becomes bigger and bigger and that Arango's exection speed is very sensible to that.

Now my question: How can I skip transaction security in AQL queries where I do not need it at all? I mean, I use temporary volatile tables, and if something really goes wrong I simply unload the table and everything is ok.

Could there be something like

```
FOR w IN relatedAffils
    COLLECT from = w._from, to = w._to INTO agg
    INSERT { "_from": from, "_to": to, "weight": LENGTH(agg), 
       "fromAff": DOCUMENT(from).affiliation,
       [...SNIP...]
       } INTO relatedAffilsAggregated OPTIONS { noTransaction }
```

Comment: Is the server running short on RAM while executing the long running INSERT query? This might explain the slowdown. If the query was from 2.4, it might be possible that it uses far less RAM in 2.5, and that this may mitigate the problem a bit.

Comment: Just to confirm: transaction security cannot be turned off in any current version of ArangoDB, even if it would possibly make sense in some cases.

Comment: I am using version 2.5 already, and RAM is not a problem at all. I am not inside the system, of course. But my guess is that the amount of records n being created (or updated) within a single aql influences the execution time in "feeled" O(square(n)). There is no index in the target collection which could slow-down the transaction.

Comment: I've made another test in which I reduced my origin query in a way that I could use COLLECT ... WITH COUNT INTO .... and did singular time measures.
GOOD: it now performs ok. There was no signifificant difference between a readonly (return) query and an insert query. BAD: I can not use functionalities like "authors": agg[*].author" in the result. As a consequence, using temporary variable in long-running AQL queries maybe is the killing point in my scenario. I try to avoid them in future as much as possible, although not always possible,

Comment: @augustin-s Could you write your solution as an answer for future references?

Comment: @13abylon: to be honest, not really. The core problems seems still to exist. The issue is either a) that high-volume-transactions lead in serious performance problems and can not be split (e.g. by turning transaction-mode off) or/and b) that queries working with many records become inefficient if I use (even small-sized) temporary variables. The only thing I saw is that while avoiding temporary variables makes the performance better, but lets me loose important expressiveness as well. In consequence, much manual low-level-tuning is necessary instead sticking to high-level AQL.

Comment: @augustin-s since a few month are gone since this issue, is this still a problem with the new versions?

Comment: To be honest, not really as I am talking about a conceptional point although also I observed the latest vesions to be faster now. The conceptional point for me is that my cases often lack of the possibility to split transactions within AQL. Yes, there is a workaround by scripting ("while not-ready repeat AQL LIMIT 100.000"), but it really would be highly benefitial to be able to express this already within the AQL-language itself.

Comment: @augustin-s: Can you retry with 3.0? Instead of `LENGTH(agg)`, you should try out `COLLECT ... AGGREGATE len = LENGTH(1)` ([docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Operations/Collect.html#aggregation)) and reduce `agg` to the attributes you actually need, preferably using `KEEP` (should be slightly faster than a projection).